# Initialize array of objects from a function (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object, initialization

How do I initialize an array of objects from a function? I'm aware the code below is impractical; I'm just teaching myself C++.

Here is a structure that contains data.

```
struct pointStruct {
    int numberPoints;
    Point2D pointArray;
};
```

The `Point2D` class has instance variables `x` and `y`. In a separate function, I have:

```
void setPoints(void) {

    pointStruct myPointData;
    myPointData.numberPoints = 4;
    myPointData.pointArray[4];      // here is the problem

    // loop with i
        myPointData.pointArray[i].x = ...;
        myPointData.pointArray[i].y = ...;
}
```

I'm trying to initialize the array so that I can loop through it and set the x,y coordinates. I've tried using `new` and some other methods but I can't work through what I need to do. How can I fix this?

When I try to compile this code, I get the error "*no match for 'operator[]' in 'myPointData.pointStruct::pointArray[4]'* "

Comment: Point2D is not an array. Personally, I'd use a vector<Point2D>, and then in for for loop with i, do myPointData.pointVector.push_back(Point2D(x,y)) (assuming Poin2D has a constructor like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `std::vector` like MadScienceDreams suggests.

However, if you want to learn about such things, you could use a pointer instead. For example:

```
struct pointStruct {
   int numberPoints;
   Point2D* pointArray;
};

void setPoints(void) {

   pointStruct myPointData;
   const int num_points = 4;
   myPointData.numberPoints = num_points;
   myPointData.pointArray = new Point2D[num_points];

   for(int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) {
       myPointData.pointArray[i].x = ...;
       myPointData.pointArray[i].y = ...;
   }

   // Do stuff with myPointData...

   // Don't forget to have a "delete" for every "new" when you're done.
   delete[] myPointData.pointArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Point2D pointArray;
```

`pointArray` is a single instance to `Point2D`. It is not an array of instances in which case it's type is `Point2D [N]`.

```
myPointData.pointArray[4];
```

The above statement calls operator `[]` taking a parameter of type `int`, which is not you actually want. Since there is no such member function in `Point2D`, compiler complains. If you wish to create array of instances, use `std::vector<Point2D>`.